# greatest common divisor of p-1 and q-1

Tags: arithmetic-progression, analytic-number-theory, nt.number-theory

Hi there,

Can we say that if $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime number diving $n$

$\Omega(gcd(p-1,q-1)) \leq \Omega(n)$

Where $\Omega(n)$ denotes the number of prime powers dividing $n$

Best
rahmi

Comment: No: let $p=13$, $q=37$ and $n=pq=481$. Then $\Omega((p-1,q-1))=\Omega(12)=3$ while $\Omega(n)=2$.

Answer (score 3):

No: take $n=211*2311$, $p=211, q=2311$. In fact there is no bound of the L.H.S. in terms of the R.H.S. in your inequality. Take any sequence of primes $p_1,...,p_s$. Let $a=p_1\cdot...\dot p_s$. By Dirichlet theorem there are two primes $p=ak+1, q=am+1$, $k < m$. Let $n=pq$. Then $\Omega(n)=2$ while $GCD(p-1,q-1)$ is divisible by $p_1,...,p_n$, so $\Omega(GCD)\ge n$.